# Matlab camera calibration getting peripheral corners

Tags: matlab, camera-calibration

I don't know why, but Matlab Camera Calibration app is getting also the peripheral corners, it is not supposed to do that. Any clues?

By the way, the border squares are more thinner by purpose, just to try to make Matlab ignore them, I also used normal squares side on the borders but I got the same Matlab behavior.

My image result:
[image: My image result]

Correct result from matlab website:
[image: Correct result from matlab website]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The thing is that Matlab usually can't handle a "perfect" image**. Since I was analyzing my patter before printing and not an actual photo of it, it seems the corner detection get lost. I just added some blur to my pattern and Matlab was able to detect it correctly. Another "solution" is to reduce the borders size, since there is no need to them to have the full rectangle size.

Perfect image
[image: Perfect image]

Perfect image + blur - OK
[image: Perfect image + blur - OK]

Perfect image with 40% borders - OK
[image: Perfect image with 40% borders - OK]
Original perfect image with 40% borders
[image: Imaged used - Perfect image with 40% borders]